# How to test models with required associations

Tags: elixir, ecto, ex-unit

Using Ecto 2.0:

```
defmodule PlexServer.BoardInstanceTest do
  use PlexServer.ModelCase

  alias PlexServer.BoardInstance

  @valid_attrs %{board_pieces: [%PlexServer.BoardTileInstance{x: 0, y: 0}], empire: %PlexServer.EmpireInstance{}}
  @invalid_attrs %{}

  test "changeset with valid attributes" do
    changeset = BoardInstance.changeset(%BoardInstance{}, @valid_attrs)
    assert changeset.valid?
  end
end

defmodule PlexServer.BoardInstance do
  use PlexServer.Web, :model

  alias PlexServer.BoardTileInstance

  schema "board_instances" do  
    belongs_to :empire, PlexServer.EmpireInstance
    has_many :board_pieces, BoardTileInstance

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w()
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
      |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
      |> cast_assoc(:board_pieces, required: true)
      |> cast_assoc(:empire, require: true)
  end
end
```

My test fails with

> ** (RuntimeError) casting assocs with cast/3 is not supported, use cast_assoc/3 instead

Looking at the documentation is says that cast_assoc/3 needs to be called after cast/3 so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something essential to get this test to work.

Edit: Updated my code and now receiving a new error:

> ** (Ecto.CastError) expected params to be a map, got: `%PlexServer.BoardTileInstance{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built>, fleets: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :fleets is not loaded>, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, system: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :system is not loaded>, updated_at: nil, x: 0, y: 0}`

I'm guessing my @valid_attrs are malformed some how?

Comment: Try removing `empire` and `board_pieces` from `@required_fields` and adding `cast_assoc` for `:empire` with `required: true`.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, @Dogbert, but unfortunately I'm still having problems.

Comment: You're getting the same error after making those two changes?

Comment: Try this: `@valid_attrs %{board_pieces: [%{x: 0, y: 0}], empire: %{}}`.

Comment: @Dogbert that worked! Thanks very much. If you want to create an answer I will accept it. I'm guessing the cast_assoc simply doesnt expect an Ecto.Schema to be passed in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You don't need to pass the names of associations to `cast` or `validate_required`. You should remove it from `@required_fields`. `cast_assoc` will handle converting those fields to structs and, if you pass `required: true`, will validate that they're present. (For those who didn't read the comments above, see [revision 1 of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37959587/revisions) for the context.)
2. `@valid_attrs` should be a normal map, like you would get as `params` in a Phoenix Controller's functions. `cast_assoc` will handle converting a raw map into a struct. So, change

   ```
   @valid_attrs %{board_pieces: [%PlexServer.BoardTileInstance{x: 0, y: 0}], empire: %PlexServer.EmpireInstance{}}
   ```

   to

   ```
   @valid_attrs %{board_pieces: [%{x: 0, y: 0}], empire: %{}}
   ```